# Data not properly fit on VEGA tree layout chart

Tags: jquery, vega

I've used

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@4.0.0-rc.2
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@3.0.0

and i've total 1500 data in json array.
For 
level 1: 1
Level 2: 20
Level 3: 1479

while rendering it's not showing properly.because it's not fit into window. so is there any way to get actual size after rendering and any other way to display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display VEGA tree layout chart if very large data then it overlap each other, we have to set enough width and height according to amount of data we have to pass. For that we need to calculate width and height while parsing chart so we need to calculate it in advance.

How to calculate in advance:
First we need to see if we have 1000 data then how much width and height it consume,

e.g it take width: 500px and height: 500px to display 1000 data properly.
make logic that it increase width and height as data increase or decrease
Let say we have 1500 data then data increased by 500 then

```
       1000  =>  500px
       1500  =>  ?

       ? = 1500 * 500 / 1000 = 750px
```

This is one possible way to set width and height dynamically, hope this help you.